# does the boot process vary with UEFI mode?

Tags: bootloader

I dont understand if there is any change in Boot Process using UEFI using GPT partition.?

files like NTDETECT, NTLDR, NTOSKRNL, HAL, WINLOGON, LSASS which is used by MBR.Are these same files used by GPT and which boot loader it uses? 
what will be the new Boot process if it changes?

Comment: Your question shows a total lack of understanding of the terms. You really need to study first the terms involved. Wikipedia is a good place to start.

Comment: More specifically: only one of those files is actually used by the MBR. Study what _order_ these files are used in, and you'll see where the BIOS boot ends and Windows boot begins.